# How do I detonate C4?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

What is the default control for detonating C4 with a mouse and keyboard?

I missed the tutorial, it's not referenced in the options or keybinds, and I continuously forgot how to do it.

Comment: The tooltip text on the weapon select dialog should tell you how to operate each weapon/item/tool with appropriate keybind information. That said, I've never played the PC version.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the PC controls show the Xbox controls, for some reason. 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To detonate C4, hold Aim (RMB by default) and simultaneously hit Use (E).

As mentioned by @Lucas-Leblanc, this also works with any of the other 'trap' items, such as the Decoy Mine.

Comment: Apologies if the self answer offend anyone - I've found myself forgetting this several days in a row, and Google is no use. Experimentation is great, just after a tank has driven past... But thankfully I can help myself and anyone else with this issue.

Comment: You should know that there are other "trap" items in the game that have the same control scheme. For instance there is an inflatable decoy that you plant on the ground, then you can deploy it when you're ready, causing a distraction. The control scheme is the same there.

Comment: Note that C4 are FIFO - the first C4 placed will be the first C4 detonated. You can detonate them by shooting them as well (and enemies can detonate yours by shooting them).

Comment: @twobugs Ah, I never noticed that - only ever seem to do multiple-in-one-patch, so far. Will have to try more complex traps!

Comment: @Jeeva: They'll cause a chain reaction, exploding one another so you don't have to hit the detonator multiple times. It's useful for a convoy to space your C4 out, however; you can plant the charge furthest along the road first, then place your other charges in a line behind it. That way, when the lead vehicle hits the first charge you planted, all of the other vehicles should be on or near the other charges, and you can hit your detonator to sequentially damage/destroy the convoy front-to-back. The lead vehicle will panic and stop upon being hit with the lead charge so the others are trapped.